# auto update field in table using phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, sql-update, triggers

I have 2 tables . Order table with unique order_id and status field. And the order_line table have one or more row for each order_id in the order table and each row have status field.
The task is to update the order table status field for an order_id with a new value when all status field in the order_line table for a particular oder_id is updated with a particular value.

How can be this done Using mysql trigger functionality

order table
[image: order table]

order_line table
[image: order_line table]

Answer (score 0):

you should create a trigger..

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-the-first-trigger-in-mysql.aspx

Comment: thanks. Can you help me in writing trigger statement. In my case trigger is called only when all rows in a table having particular oder_id has updated with status 1.

Comment: you should give the detail of your table schema..then i might be able to help you

Comment: I have modified the question. Please check